# How to put rpcgen-generated server and client in same executable

Tags: c, rpc

if I generate server and client stubs, the names will be the same, so linker can not create executable due to symbol name collision. How can I come around this the easiest way?

Comment: Add some prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the error was in my setup.
I used the -k option for rpcgen, that resulted in the strange behavior: it did generate only one function name for one function:

```
returnType function_1();
```

instead of

```
returnType function_1(void *, CLIENT *);
returnType function_1_svc(void *, struct svc_req *);
```

-k is an undocumented parameter, and from rpcgen's source code it turns out to be the K&R style code generation (that is the opposite of ANSI C). It defines only one function (no other function with _svc postfix), and without parameter.